# Debugging issues with Adobe DTM rules not being captured in Adobe SiteCatalyst report suites?

Tags: adobe-analytics

I set up a web property with a couple of rules in Adobe Dynamic Tag Manager. I'm using the DTM Debugger Chrome extension, I'm able to verify that `satellite.js` is picking up on the fact that the rule conditions are being met and that a request is being sent off to my Adobe DTM instance:

```
SATELLITE: Rule "Callout Click" fired.
SATELLITE: Adobe Analytics: tracked link using: linkTrackVars="eVar29,prop20,events"; linkTrackEvents="event26"
```

However, the event isn't showing up in my Adobe Analytics report suite and no errors are being thrown in either the Adobe SiteCatalyst interface nor the DTM interface.

I'm having a pretty hard time trying to figure out how to debug the problem from here.

- What does the pipeline look like after a DTM rule is fired off on the front-end?
- Are there any common things to look for when DTM seems to be working but SiteCatalyst doesn't show the props/events/evars/whatever on the report suite?
- Where is the supporting documentation for Adobe Analytics/SiteCatalyst?

Comment: I also have a very similar issue, i've used all the debugging tools under the sun - Tagtician is one of the more recent debuggers, and it shoes that satellite is firing the events, but they're not making it into AA. Where do we go from here? Adobe's documentation isn't great.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you can see your DTM rules successfully fire using the console but can you also confirm that an Adobe Analytics image request has been sent?

The easiest way to determine this is to use the network tab and filter on "/b/ss". These are specific values you'd expect to see coming from the image request. You will want to look for this when / if your rule fires successfully.

Once you have a successful image request you can troubleshoot the rule or Adobe Analytics config if you don't see data in the UI.

Hope this helps.
Mark

Comment: Yep, in this instance, DTM was firing off successfully but the report suite wasn't receiving the data from DTM.  I'm mostly interested in what happens after DTM fires off and gets sent to SiteCatalyst - I'd like to figure out what debugging options are available at that point.